windows based dockerfile with python install
I want to implement a windows based dockerfile which can be used to install python as well.
these are some of the commands I have, I want to troubleshoot the part where in it install python explicitly.
# Use Windows Server Core as the base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# Install Python 3.12.2
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download and install Python
RUN curl -o python-installer.exe https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/python-3.12.2-amd64.exe && \
    python-installer.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 && \
    del python-installer.exe


Have you tried splitting the RUN command? Chaining commands are great for reducing layers but not for debugging which step went wrong

sure, i will try splitting the RUN command
